# Issue with weights in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is logs about issue from terminal in VS, as I notice that the issue is connected with weight and resnet50:

```
2021-12-09 14:13:05.990253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Found 1150 images belonging to 6 classes.
Found 69 images belonging to 3 classes.
2021-12-09 14:13:07.597333: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.620200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0 name: GeForce GT 710 computeCapability: 3.5
coreClock: 0.954GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2021-12-09 14:13:07.620290: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.626040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.626153: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.629388: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.630584: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.634544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.637477: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.638137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:07.638274: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-12-09 14:13:07.638762: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-12-09 14:13:07.639495: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0 name: GeForce GT 710 computeCapability: 3.5
coreClock: 0.954GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2021-12-09 14:13:07.639637: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-12-09 14:13:08.054229: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-12-09 14:13:08.054494: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-12-09 14:13:08.055724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-12-09 14:13:08.056304: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1401 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 710, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
2021-12-09 14:13:09.783481: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/20
2021-12-09 14:13:11.729552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:11.994194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:359] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
2021-12-09 14:13:12.881136: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-12-09 14:13:13.119825: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\training2\1.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=3, epochs=20, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=1)
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\kamil\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[24,10] labels_size=[24,6]
         [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\training2\1.py:47) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_9664]

Function call stack:
train_function

2021-12-09 14:13:20.601044: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

My very first Tensorflow project, please help to solve this issue. I use pre-trained model and my own pictures, and my own json file with 3 classes for objects recognition.
Thank you very much in advance!

```
image_size = 224

data_generator_with_aug = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, 
                                             horizontal_flip=True,
                                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                                             height_shift_range=0.2)
train_path='C:/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/training2/training'
train_generator = data_generator_with_aug.flow_from_directory(train_path, 
                                                     target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
                                                     batch_size=24,
                                                     class_mode='categorical')

data_generator_with_no_aug = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

validation_path='C:/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/training2/validation'
validation_generator = data_generator_with_no_aug.flow_from_directory(validation_path,
                                                          target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                          batch_size=24,
                                                          class_mode='categorical')




#resnet_weights_path = 'imagenet'

model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights='imagenet'))

num_classes = 10
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=3, epochs=20, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=1)
```

Comment: Your traceback is incomplete, it does not say what error/exception happened.

Comment: I add whole text from terminal wich I understand you want to see

Comment: It is likely that the path you passed as weights does not exist (os.path.exists on that path returns False).

Comment: I  change path but issue is still exist

Comment: What does os.path.exists return on your path?

Comment: I installed SkyPy and now I have different error